# how to programmatically enable and disable USB in android Application

Tags: android, usb

in my application i want to enable / disable the USB connection in the phone or tab(Android based) programmatically.I googled , but did not find any solution.If it is possible give me some ideas to do this.or provide some useful code for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible from the Android SDK.

Answer (score 6):

I know it is too late but it would be helpful to others.. 
In API 12 Android 3.1 or higher , there is a UsbManager class has been introduced,

Check this link. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but your application should own the device, by owning the device you can use the [DevicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#addUserRestriction(android.content.ComponentName,%2520java.lang.String)) method, as follows:

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager =
            (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

if (devicePolicyManager != null && isDeviceOwnerApp(context)) {
   devicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(componentName, UserManager.DISALLOW_USB_FILE_TRANSFER);
}
```