# how disable/block USB

Tags: android

Programmaticslly I want disable USB data read. There is no meaning or purpose.I just want to learn whether it is possible or not. In order to clarify, how can I disable USB connection? ( sort of unpluggin)

Answer (score 0):

As per the accepted answer below, it is not possible at the moment.

[How to programmatically enable and disable USB in android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10140671/867591)

Comment: Is it possible with Androind Linux or own comnands ?

Comment: Would you like to disable the USB when your app is running or always for the handset?

Comment: Just for configuration, I want disable it while user click on the disable USB button.

Comment: IMHO, it is not possible but you can play around with the below Android API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this command in android terminal emulator. Root priveleges required:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/virtual/android_usb/android0/enable
```

or...

```
su -c 'echo 0 > /sys/devices/virtual/android_usb/android0/enable'
```